# Why is it ok to be called Muhammad?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Why is it ok to name some o Muhammad, but it's not allowed to depict him? Shouldn't that be equally blasphemous? I know at least two muslim men who are named after the prophet but with slightly different spelling, Mohammad and Muhammed.

Comment: Because depiction is forbidden in Islam. Naming people is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your question. I ask Allah guide all towards that which is good, ameen. 
For something to be forbidden in Islam, it must have a basis in the Quran, Sunnah (prophetic traditions) or Ijma (consensus) of the scholars. With regards to names, the Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him) said,

> **إِنَّكُمْ تُدْعَوْنَ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ بِأَسْمَائِكُمْ
>   وَأَسْمَاءِ آبَائِكُمْ فَأَحْسِنُوا أَسْمَاءَكُمْ**
>
> **"You will be called on the Day of Resurrection by your names and the names of your fathers, so have good names."** (Reported by Abu Dawud)

With the above saying of the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) in mind, one can conclude that "Muhammad" is a good name and since there is no valid reason not to name someone Muhammad, it is perfectly fine to do so.

And Allah Knows best

Comment: So there are bad names in Islam? Then again, perhaps there are in Christianity as well, haven't really checked.

Comment: @Sandokan - Yes there are. The Prophet has changed the names of a few Sahaba who had bad names. For instance, Abu Huraiyrah was named Abdu Shams (servant of the sun), and the Prophet changed it to Abdu Rahman (servant of the most merciful)